# Update DataGridView from another class

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, delegates

my purpose is refresh or update a DataGridView that get data from database and show them to the user. 
The application is composed by several form (and classes) in the same namespace, in this case I'm referring to:

- `Function_Map` class that contains `dataGridView2`
- `Tool_Field` class that contains the control able to add rows to the database

What I'm expecting is that when an user adds a row to the database from `Tool_Field` the system updates automatically the dataGridView2 control in `Function_Map` class. In my mind

I think that solution could be call the function

```
private void SetDatagrid()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.DataBasePath);

    Settings.DBAccess.FillDataGridViewFromReg(ref table);

    conn.Close();
}
```

For this reason I declared in the `Tool_Field`

```
public delegate void Update_Table_Delegate();

...

private void BT_ToolField_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Update_Table_Delegate Update_Table = new Update_Table_Delegate(Function_Map.SetDatagrid);

    ... // Add row in database

    Update_Table();
    ...
}
```

The error that occur is `Error  6 It should be a reference to an object property, method, or field is not static`.
I can solve this issue changing the line

```
Update_Table_Delegate Update_Table = 
new Update_Table_Delegate(Function_RegisterMap.SetDatagrid);
```

with

```
Update_Table_Delegate Update_Table = 
new Update_Table_Delegate(Function_RegisterMap.SetDatagrid2);
```

where SetDatagrid2 is declared static but, in this case, is not possible to acces to dataGridView2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need a `event` to update the `grid`.
In `Tool_Field` class, make the following changes.

```
public delegate void Update_Table_Delegate(); //already declared
public event Update_Table_Delegate Changed; //declare event
//invoke event
public void OnChanged()
{
   if(Changed != null)
     Changed();
}
```

In the `BT_ToolField_Click` method call the `OnChanged`.

In the `Function_Map` class

```
 //put in c'tor or any appropriate place
 Tool_Field.Changed += new Update_Table_Delegate(SetDatagrid);
```

Let me know if it helps you.